# Check if click occured inside or outside of modal window

Tags: jquery, css

I am catching click on website and closing modal window.

But how to actually check if click occured inside or outside of modal window?

```
    $(document).click(callself(this, function (inst, event) {
        var modalElement = $(selector);
        if (modalElement.css("display") == "block") {
            this.closeButtonClicked();
        }
    }));
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets say your modal window id is `modal`.

with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        console.log('document is clicked');
    });

    $('#modal').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('modal is clicked');
    });
});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Cool, it's even better than CSS3 `pointer-events:none;`

Comment: and css3 isn't supported in some browsers. javascript approach is.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work on `position:absolute` elements?

Comment: well, yes- it should work on them ether.

Comment: Nope it's not. Relative elements are ok.